# Symfony Dynamic Form Constraints

Tags: symfony

Looking for a straightforward way to add constraints dynamically to all of my form fields.  So far I've hit upon the idea of using a [form type extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html), which *kind of* works: I can modify the form *view* and then manually check the view on form submission.

However, is there a smarter way to add real Symfony-based constraints in real-time?

(Note that the constraints need to be added to the form in real-time as the form loads based on user configuration in the database.. Predefined form groups and the like won't work.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use form events.

Use the [PRE_SUBMIT](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-submit-event) event to edit the form before validation.

Recreate your fields with `$event->getForm()->add(...)` adding your constraints.

Of course you can automatically add the listener to all form using a FormExtension which adds the listener.

**EDIT** : Some examples from [Alsatian67/FormBundle](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/tree/master/Form/Extensions)

---

Your extension should looks like :

```
class ExtensibleExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    private $extensibleSubscriber;
    public function __construct($extensibleSubscriber) {
        $this->extensibleSubscriber = $extensibleSubscriber;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Only apply on base form
        if($builder->getForm()->isRoot())
        {
            $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->extensibleSubscriber);
        }
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```

And your EventListener / EventSubscriber should iterate on all the children :

```
foreach($event->getForm()->all() as $child){
    $childName = $child->getName();
    $type = get_class($child->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType());
    $options = $child->getConfig()->getOptions();

    $options['constraints'] = array(/* ... */);

    $form->add($childName,$type,$options);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks.. I never would have thought of using form events inside a form type extension.  But since my type extension would be called for every form field, wouldn't `$event->getForm()->add(...)` need to replace itself?  How would I do that?

Comment: Have a look on the edit. (My example uses an EventSubscriber injected as service. But your can do the same with an EventListener as closure).

Comment: Aha, avoid the recursive field walking of `FormType::class` by checking for the root form. Nice!

Comment: One last question:  I notice that if I have a constraint manually defined in a type (e.g. `'constraints' => [new Assert\NotNull(['groups' => 'Registration'])]`, this seems to ultimately clobber the constraints I add dynamically in `PRE_SUBMIT`.  Any way to workaround this?

Comment: By `$options['constraints'] = array(/* ... */);` just push your new constraint ?

Comment: No luck.  If I define `'constraints'` inside of a type, the constraints I define in my listener closer are either ignored or replaced.  If I move the constraint to entity annotations.. no problem.

Comment: OK, no idea :/. You can ask a new question `how to access form constraints in a PRE_SUBMIT event`